# Set ipad compatible thumbs for mp4 videos based on a frame of the video with command line

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mac

I have a directory of 100 mp4 files. All are working well on my ipad but most of them do not have a working thumb.

I want to generate these thumbs with a command line command (on macosx) based on a frame of the movies (at second 30 for example).

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the difference between the videos that do have a "working thumb" and ones that do not?

Comment: I dont have any idea. It is very weird because i dont have the same results in OSX.

Comment: Do you see any differences within the `ffmpeg` console output? `ffmpeg -i works.mp4 -i notwork.mp4`?

Comment: Is this in the iPad's native *Videos* app?

Comment: This is how it looks in Finder http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cb653aicns4xtql/2014-02-19%20at%2009.57.png

Comment: It's worse on ipad with the native Video app https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/n629jjphzkjqv6z/2014-02-19%20at%2010.00.png

Comment: When i try to update the illustration with iTunes, the tab is just disabled for some videos. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1q7phyyqwypxc6v/2014-02-19%20at%2010.07.png

Comment: I get errors when using ffmpeg https://gist.github.com/iesta/9088516